# Vue register component keep failing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, web-frontend

I'm doing a FE based on [THIS VUE TEMPLATE][https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-material-dashboard-pro]

I am trying to register a component locally, but I keep getting the error:

> "103:5   error    The "BFCookieCard" component has been registered but
> not used"

I did not have any success with the answers shared in:

- [I'm getting an error of 13:5 error The “Home” component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402610/im-getting-an-error-of-135-error-the-home-component-has-been-registered-but)
- [component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821385/component-has-been-registered-but-not-used-vue-no-unused-components)
- [Vue component defined but not used error message. How do I use it properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382062/vue-component-defined-but-not-used-error-message-how-do-i-use-it-properly)
- [Remove 'component has been registered but not used' in eslint for Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258991/remove-component-has-been-registered-but-not-used-in-eslint-for-vue-js)

My Files are as follows:

**BFConsentCookie.vue**

```
<template>
  
    <h1> HELLO </h1>
  
</template>

<script>
 
export default {
  name: "bf-cookie-card",

  data() {
    return {};
  },
  beforeMount() {
    
  },
}
```

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
<div> 
          <bf-cookie-card>
          </bf-cookie-card>
      
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
<script>

import { BFCookieCard} from "@/components";


export default {
  components: {
    BFCookieCard,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
}
```

**index.js**

```
import BFCookieCard from "./Cards/BFCookieCard.vue";
export {
    BFCookieCard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the capital F in BFCookieCard, replace it with BfCookieCard.
In your login.vue you can also import your component like that:

```js
components: {
    BfCookieCard: () => import('path to component file.vue'),
},
```

Comment: Awesome. Now the component is registered with no errors. Now I cannot see any "HELLO" printed on the main screen. The expected behavior is to show that string, right?

Comment: No, you should see the hello string. Now your index.js file looks like this?
import BfCookieCard from "./Cards/BFCookieCard.vue"; export {
    BfCookieCard
}